# NLog Core 2.0 logs automatically

Tags: logging, .net-core, nlog

I'm building an API using .Net Core 2.0.

I'm setting up NLog for logging but there are some "mysteries" that I can't figure out.

I have followed [this](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2) configuration but I don't understand 2 things:

1. How Nlog differentiate `nlog-all` from `nlog-own`. I mean, the rules are the same for both files:

   ```
   <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />

   <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-web" />
   ```
2. Why NLog logs to `nlog-all` automatically? How can I take control over it?
3. Yes I lied, I said 2 things, but what's the point of configuring `appsettings.json`if everything is to be configured in the xml `nlog.config` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic happens in the logging-rule that you have nicely excluded from the example:

```
  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />

    <!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxLevel="Info" final="true" /> <!-- BlackHole without writeTo -->

    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-web" />
  </rules>
```

The logging rules are evaluated from top to bottom:

- The top "allFile"-rule will match all logger (name="*")
- The middle BlackHole-rule will match all Microsoft-loggers and because of final="true" then it will stop further matching.
- The last "ownFile" will then receive everything from all loggers not starting with Microsoft.

See also https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules

See also https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial